# Android database returning path to item and not actual item

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to get the actual items from a database but my method seems to be returning a path. Any help will be much appreciated.

Method to get all products:

```
// Getting All Products
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                product.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                product.setImage(cursor.getString(2));
                product.setPrice(cursor.getFloat(3));


                // Adding product to list
                productList.add(product);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return product list
        return productList;
    }
```

My array adapter:

```
products = db.getAllProducts();
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(MainPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
                    productList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is how it is returning it into the list view:
"com.handy.shoppy.Product@43e9578"

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of `ArrayAdapter` calls `toString()` on the list of Objects that it holds. The default implementation of `toString()` simply gives you the `ClassName@hashCode`

You could override `toString()` in `Product` so that it outputs the member fields but a *better* approach is to subclass [`ArrayAdapter` and override the `getView()`](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) method so that you assign each property of your `Product` to a specific `View` in the row layout.